# How to refresh Semantic UI after adding new content with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, semantic-ui

I use the Semantic UI CSS / JS for Responsive Design

The JS for Dropdown Boxes in UI Style and all other Elements are working after page loading.

But what if i add some additional Form Fields with an Ajax Request, adding the Content in the DOM... How i can "refresh" all Semantic UI Elements, that they are working just like after a Page Reload?

In the Foundation Framework it was possible with DomObject.foundation();

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to re-initialize Semantic UI after adjusting the DOM.  For instance if you add a new dropdown

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
```

Semantic UI also [has some API](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#match-search-query-on-server) functionality to retrieve remote content (dropdown choices for instance).

Comment: really? hm... but even a radio Button doesn't work... there is no funktion to refresh all UI Functionality with a new DOM? Like after loading the Page Content?